# E-Commerce database design - CUSTOMER table - EMAIL/PHONE login - Primary Key & Customer Role

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, e-commerce

I am designing an e-commerce database wherein user can login into the application using his/her email Id. So I have a couple of questions pertaining to CUSTOMER table, that am not sure of what actually could be the best design.

**Question #1:** Usually it is good to have an ID (auto-increment number) as Primary Key for CUSTOMER table considering ease of use in other tables as Foreign key, always good to have a record ID as a number and also we can see the max(ID) to get the total number of customers. Now since EMAIL is used as UserName to log in --- Do I have to make email as primary key? If not, what constraint should be applied to Email & what value those constraints add to the Email column?

**Question #2:** Further to question #1, if I want to allow the user to login with EMAIL or PHONE NUMBER, how does my CUSTOMER table accommodate this? I mean what will be my primary key & what constraints should be added on ID, EMAIL, and PHONE NUMBER?

**Question #3:** As I am using Spring Security for Authentication, it can accommodate ROLES or GRANTED AUTHORITIES in Authentication object. Since it's an e-commerce application and all the customers/users have the same access, do I have to still keep ROLES assigned to each CUSTOMER? Does it make sense considering proper design and scalability OR it just adds an overhead in Login & we can go without having any role assigned to the customer?

Comment: One question per question please

Comment: @RiggsFolly - It's a single question that I have broken down into three parts for readability.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your first question:
You should have a customerID field which is auto increment and primary key(which you are already talking about).You are using the email as a username for authentication purposes so it can be "NOT NULL" and "UNIQUE"(doesn't necessarily need to be a Primary Key.Having keys unnecessarily is a headache as my teacher says).

To answer your second question:
Do you want to absolutely implement a rule to include the phone number?If yes then you can have the phone_number field as a "NOT NULL" and "UNIQUE"(again not necessarily a Primary Key).
If no,then just don't implement any constraints except for "UNIQUE"​ on it and the authentication will be done only if a phone number is present and if phone number is null then no login.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Just NOT NULL won't work. It should be UNIQUE. I am looking for better real time solution or approach as it has today with successfully running ecomm sites.

Comment: But you can make the email field Primary Key as it will be the default login name I assume.